# IIS http response headers are getting mixed

Tags: iis

Why are the response headers in IIS getting jumbled? I used the IIS gui to set 5 response headers: Content-Security-Policy,Referrer-Policy, Strict-Transport-Security, X-Xss-Protection, and X-Frame-Option?

Answer (score 1):

Using the following curl statement
 curl -IkL --verbose https://webhostname.domain.com

I found that the values for IIS response headers were shifting. I found in the http response headers an etag item that didn't have a value. The next header value had moved to the etag value, etc. So all values had shifted up 1 line as it filled the  values from top to bottom ... and etag was at the top.

Unsure of proper use of etag. But, I deleted the item and retested with the curl statement and functionality was great.